# What type of adapter do I need to connect my water supply lines?

Tags: kitchens, faucet

My last faucet started to leak, so I just bought a new Moen one.  I just about got it installed, but when I tried to hook up the water lines, I have two female connectors that don't seem to like each other.

The faucet I was replacing (also a Moen), had a metal pipe with a male connector.  However, the new one has a supply line hose with a female connector at the end.  The water line is a pex plastic tube with a female connector at the end.

Do I need some sort of adapter?

Comment: Are there shutoff valves under the sink? Typically the incoming water lines would connect to a shutoff valve, then the fixture supply lines would connect to the other side of the valve.

Comment: That's the problem, I don't have shutoff valves there, there are just rubber tubes (called "pex" according to my plumber uncle) coming out the wall that run all the way down to a manifold in the basement.

Comment: Then instead of using a straight adapter, I'd install a shutoff valve instead. Something like [this](http://lh4.googleusercontent.com/public/jcMtUMjlDyM5-ZUr3a4oKHxuZ_yRfi1BWw8N4NcYEsO8ErjQjv3SslzBBB1f985k3o7lnVSCmbWSunU4KI58R6bdmyZqY36Kv2H7QV_Cp4xNKiIokfxC7JCx9HGgabayfDOHDcyg0BhtagYADz-B4Tn2OnMRLB0gm0OCLXhb) .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Faucets are usually 3/8, so you would need a 3/8 brass nipple

[image]

If not, they sell many different size brass nipples.